# fast way to find the index of the closest from an array to each element in another array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I want to find a faster way to get the index of the nearest element in array of shape `(k,l)` to each element in another array of shape `(n,l)`, I found 2 solutions but I think the performance can be improved.

here is an example

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.matlib as ml

frames = np.random.random([1000,2])
codeBook = np.random.random([8,2])
```

I

```
dist = np.zeros([frames .shape[0],codeBook.shape[0]])
for i in range(8):
    difference = frames - ml.repmat(codeBook[i,:],frames.shape[0],1)
    dist[:,i] = np.sqrt(np.sum(difference**2,1)) 
idx = np.argmin(dist,axis=1)
```

II

```
diffToCB =  frames - np.rot90(ml.repmat(codeBook,frames.shape[0],1).reshape(-1,8,2),axes=(1,0))
idx = np.argmin(np.sqrt(np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij', diffToCB, diffToCB)) , axis=0)
```

Comment: have a look at  [KD trees](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html)

Comment: I tried it with different leafsizes but it was always slower than `einsum` approach